# How to implement forms for sets and supersets of objects with Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Imagine the following two Django models:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    '''
    A single Item of something.
    '''
    name = models.CharField(unique = True)
    sets = model.ManyToManyField('Set', blank = True)

    def get_supersets(self):
    '''
    Returns the list of all the supersets the item belongs to EXCLUDING the
    directly linked sets.
    '''
    res = []
    for set in self.sets:
        res = res + set.get_all_supersets()
    return res
    

class Set(models.Model):
    '''
    A set of items which can either contain items or not (empty set allowed).
    Sets can be grouped in supersets. Supersets will contain all items of 
    the related subsets.
    '''
    name = models.CharField(unique = True)
    superset = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null = True, blank = True)
    # Note: Self-reference to the same object is avoided by excluding it 
      from the forms queryset for the superset field. 

    def get_all_spersets(self):
    '''
    Returns all supersets of the set.
    '''
    if self.superset:
        return [self.superset] + self.superset.get_all_supersets()
    else:
        return []
```

I found two options for implementing the connection between supersets and the corresponding items of the sets in a given superset:

1. On saving a set or an item update the item_set of the supersets. With this, all relations will be stored in the database. This also needs to include some logic regarding circular relations.
2. Decide for "direct-links-only", which means an item will only be linked to its directly related set in the database. The relations to the supersets will be found on the fly if requested (e.g. get all supersets) with model methods.

For me, option 2 seems much more attractive in terms of data integrity since connected relations will be updated on the fly. However, once a user enters an item -> set relation one needs to make sure the user does not unnecessarily select a superset of a set the item already belongs to, which would break the logic and in the worst case lead to infinite recursion in the model methods to retrieve the supersets.

Since the selection will take place in a form, the Item form looks like this:

```
class ItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.fields['sets'].queryset = Set.objects.all()
        # For now, this shows all available sets. One could limit this 
          queryset to only the sets not in the items get_superset().
          However, this would not allow the user to see which supersets
          the item already belongs to.

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        widgets = {'sets': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()}
        # Available sets are shown as checkboxes.
```

The Set form looks like this:

```
class SetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self):
        self.fields['superset'].queryset = Set.objects.all.exclude(id__exact=self.instance.id)
        # As mentioned, avoiding self-reference.
    
    class Meta:
        model = Set
```

**My question:**

1. How can I show the Items supersets in the ItemForm but avoid that a user chooses them?
2. If a user chooses a set, which is part of a superset, this superset should immediately become unavailable in the ItemForm. Is something like this possible and how?